# Can I install standard drivers in a windows 7 macbook?

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, boot-camp

Can I simple format the macbook pro HD and install windows 7 then use the bootcamp drivers inside the macos dvd? Does Windows 7 installation in a mac use the same drivers as a standard PC (I mean nvidia geforce drivers, audio drivers, etc)?

Comment: Since you have to install Windows 7 no matter what, have you simply tried it, before asking this question?

Comment: No because I don't own the system yet, it's just that the hardware pack apple is selling with the 2012 macbook pro is fantastic for gamming. But i'm a windows lover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes it does.  However, it is more advisable to run the bootcamp assistant from within Mac  OSx first to get the drivers.  The reason being that the drivers the unit shipped with are not likely the most current/stable drivers.  In several models of MacBooks, the original drivers available had conflicts with other software/windows processes.

You access bootcamp assistant from the Applications/Tools menu in Mac OSx.  From there, it will let you copy all the most up to date drivers to a USB flash drive for after you install Windows 7.

I hope this helps you.

source: I own a MacBook Air with Windows 7 installed as the only OS

Comment: Can't I for example just download nvidia drivers in windows 7 and install? Does it have to be via apple? Also, how is the OPTIMUS support in a MAC with Windows 7?